# Java + Thread Control Methods

Tags: java, multithreading

I stuck in a middle of threading issues especially involving timing. I know Thread.wait, Thread.notify, Thread.sleep, Thread.yield and LockSupport.parkXXX. Are there any other methods that can be used to influence timing of a thread execution?

I would like to have something like yield but more ideally with a better control.

Is there a way to maitain information about the scheduler the os is using? I mean like the slices it allocates at normal, control the slice duration for one ore multiple threads etc... .

I want to get microsecond resolution without active (busy) waiting. Is there a way to even buzy wait using idle operation codes/ system functions?

PS: I will ask a similar question for C.

Comment: Have you considered using TimerTask?

Comment: TimerTask has the same resultion problem. I need microseconds and waiting for ms does introduce many problems. Using active waiting works fine but does not scale beyond the number of cores for appearent reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum time slice for Linux and most OSes is 0.1 ms or 1/10,000 of 1 second.

If you want full control of a CPU, I suggest busy waiting on an isolated CPU with interrupts turned off, though you will see some jitter of 10 - 40 micro-seconds. If you don't busy wait on an isolated CPU you can see jitter in the order of 5 - 50 ms. On a virtual machine jitter of 50 ms is surprisingly common.

You can test this on your machine with [MicroJitterSampler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue/blob/master/chronicle-demo/src/main/java/vanilla/java/processingengine/MicroJitterSampler.java) You can comment out the lines for Affinity if you don't have that library (though as mentioned you will see a lot of noise)

Comment: For core affinity I have my own layer for Linux but not for windows yet.

So basically I will not be able to reliable utilize yield unless I can ensure that one thread less than the number of cores is present?

Comment: And since Vista Windows is not into scheduling based on time slices anymore but rather is adaptive is there a chance to employ this?

I liked the idea to schedule with 100ns precision. Are there any settings on the OS level I can change to provide additional precision?

Comment: By your experience is the jitter hardware dependend (can faster hardware reduce the jitter) or is it OS specific?

Comment: @MartinKersten you can only have less active threads than logical CPUs.  Ideally you shouldn't be busy waiting on more than about half your logical CPUs.

Comment: @MartinKersten I am not aware of any way to change the timeslice used by an operating system. I don't believe the adaptive algos are for more precision but rather to reduce the overhead.

Comment: @MartinKersten mostly the OS is the cause of jitter.  Hardware only matters when you are doing IO, which I imagine will be some of the time.

Comment: Regarding the Hardware only matters for IO, I was thinking about faster hardware results in smaller slices choosen by the operating system. So basically in your experience the OS you have seen does not adapt to the processing capabilities that well because they focus of reducing overhead and only try to optimize the responsiveness as experienced by the user rather than programs?

Comment: @MartinKersten faster CPUs can mean the thread blocks in shorter time, but the OS doesn't preempt the thread any faster. Most OSes are not designed for real time concerns, if a delay is too short for a human to see, it's less likely to get fixed.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Also I noticed that putting a thread on very high priority provides a better Thread.yield experience (under heavy load) but way to unstable to be considered for my problem. I will do my own thread scheduling and let two tasks do active waiting but performing the task for 1000 or more 'emulated' logical threads. The jitter is quite small but sometimes a thread experience a pause of 40 or more ms. The chance that two are blocked the same time was less then one in a billion for a single task. I compensate this other way around. It is inhouse so its ok.